# iPad detect if the user has Dark Mode enabled, without supporting Dark Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, ios13, ios-darkmode

I'm working on an iPad app. I would like to know if a user has Dark Mode turned on, without actually supporting Dark Mode.

When I have my iPad in Dark Mode, and I ask the O.S for the `userInterfaceStyle` it always returns `1` (Light Mode).

In my `info.plist` I've set the `User Interface Style` to `Light`. When I remove this value, asking the O.S for the `userInterfaceStyle`, I get the correct value.

I understand that we should "just support it", however I need evidence that user's are actually using it before I can allocate the resources necessary to complete the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `info.plist` key, the style will be overridden on the system level and your app will never receive the user's setting.

Alternatively, you could remove the `plist` key and instead set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` on your main window. All subviews of that window will render in light appearance, but you should be able to check for the system style.

By the way, I think a lot of users are using Dark Mode by now, so it's probably worth the effort.